# How to change the color of a UIButton in a Table View Cell in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uisearchbar, uitableview

I have a custom TableViewCell that has a product name, product image, and button. In the same TableViewController there is a search bar that will pull up the specific products based on the name. When I search I can click on the button for the product and I would like for it to change color, from green to red and the text to change from "original color" to "changed color". This works until I cancel the search, then the button reverts back to its original form. This is the function, if you need to know anything else let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
  @IBAction func changeColorAction(sender: UIButton)
{

    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    sender.setTitle("changed Color", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

This is where I call the function:

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomSearchCell

    var user : UserItem

    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        user = self.filteredProducts[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        user = self.productsArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.followButton.addTarget(self, action: "changeColorAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    cell.configureCellWith(user)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the Search is cancelled or renewed, the table rebuilds itself from the "filterdProducts" or the "productsArray" Arrays. So you have to change the color of the button when you create the cell inside the tableView function and store the information if a product is "followed" or not.